# Show hidden fieldset after selecting dropdown option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, show-hide

The goal here is to hide the "State Championships" fieldset unless State Championships is selected from the dropdown. This works in jSFiddle, but for some reason it's not working on the live page.

Please help.

**Relevant CSS/JS code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #state-championships-1409369394 {
   display:none
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DROPDOWN_21-3-0-1').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'State Championships') {
            $("#state-championships-1409369394").show();
        } else {
            $("#state-championships-1409369394").hide();
        }
    });
});
});//]]>
</script>
```

**Relevant HTML Code**

```
    <select name="DROPDOWN_21" title="Must choose an event to register for." class="required  ee-reg-page-questions DROPDOWN_21 valid" id="DROPDOWN_21-3-0-1">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="Main Event">Main Event</option>
    <option value="State Championships">State Championships</option>
</select>

 <fieldset class="event_questions" id="state-championships-1409369394">
    <h4 class="reg-quest-title section-title">State Championships</h4>
    <div class="event_form_field">
        <label for="TEXT_18" class="ee-reg-page-questions">Qualifying Total</label>
        <input type="text" class="ee-reg-page-questions ee-reg-page-text-input  TEXT_18" id="TEXT_18-3-0-1" name="TEXT_18" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="event_form_field">
        <label for="TEXT_19" class="ee-reg-page-questions">Event Name for Qualifying Ttoal</label>
        <input type="text" class="ee-reg-page-questions ee-reg-page-text-input  TEXT_19" id="TEXT_19-3-0-1" name="TEXT_19" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="event_form_field event-quest-group-textarea">
        <label for="TEXTAREA_20" class="ee-reg-page-questions">Date of Event</label>
        <textarea class="ee-reg-page-questions ee-reg-page-text-input  TEXTAREA_20" id="TEXTAREA_20-3-0-1" name="TEXTAREA_20" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Link to JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/v4gNL/100/
**Link to Live Site:** http://bit.ly/1qeet9A

Comment: fix another console error. It should resolve it.

Comment: @Yogesh, Any idea what the conflicting error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery in place of $:

```
jQuery('#DROPDOWN_21-3-0-1').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'State Championships') {
            jQuery("#state-championships-1409369394").show();
        } else {
            jQuery("#state-championships-1409369394").hide();
        }
    });
```

You can run above script in console and check.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Yogesh, but still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not  funtion" error but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @tdzl strange. I just pasted above script in console and it started working just fine.

Comment: yeah same here. Works in the console, but when I change in the code it doesn't fix it.

Comment: @tdzl Probably, you need to replace all of your $ to jQuery.

Comment: that worked! I replaced just the section from JSFiddle and forgot to do the others. It works now. Many thanks!